# My site won't load google embed map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I get the following message in the console. It is a wordpress site. This map displayed when I had the site at another domain on the same host.It doesn't work in any browser, not just chrome.  Here is the code:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
chrome-extension://cifndhjjchjamcecpjhpggeaacihcjnl/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : undefined
chrome-extension://cifndhjjchjamcecpjhpggeaacihcjnl/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : undefined
chrome-extension://cifndhjjchjamcecpjhpggeaacihcjnl/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : document ready
chrome-extension://cifndhjjchjamcecpjhpggeaacihcjnl/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : running callback
chrome-extension://cifndhjjchjamcecpjhpggeaacihcjnl/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : undefined
chrome-extension://cifndhjjchjamcecpjhpggeaacihcjnl/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : firing tab complete
chrome-extension://cifndhjjchjamcecpjhpggeaacihcjnl/contentScript.js:80 cS: sending TAB_COMPLETE
chrome-extension://gafhhbahpojnjfhpepjjfjojbphnogmn/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : undefined
chrome-extension://gafhhbahpojnjfhpepjjfjojbphnogmn/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : undefined
chrome-extension://gafhhbahpojnjfhpepjjfjojbphnogmn/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : document ready
chrome-extension://gafhhbahpojnjfhpepjjfjojbphnogmn/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : running callback
chrome-extension://gafhhbahpojnjfhpepjjfjojbphnogmn/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : undefined
chrome-extension://gafhhbahpojnjfhpepjjfjojbphnogmn/contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : firing tab complete
chrome-extension://gafhhbahpojnjfhpepjjfjojbphnogmn/contentScript.js:80 cS: sending TAB_COMPLETE
chrome-extension://cifndhjjchjamcecpjhpggeaacihcjnl/js/scriptInjector.js:193 sI: inside WIDGET_CONTENT_MESSAGE message listener: MessageEvent
chrome-extension://cifndhjjchjamcecpjhpggeaacihcjnl/js/scriptInjector.js:194 MessageEvent
chrome-extension://gafhhbahpojnjfhpepjjfjojbphnogmn/js/scriptInjector.js:193 sI: inside WIDGET_CONTENT_MESSAGE message listener: MessageEvent
chrome-extension://gafhhbahpojnjfhpepjjfjojbphnogmn/js/scriptInjector.js:194 MessageEvent
contentScript.js:234 cs: onRequestListener(Arguments[3])
contentScript.js:234 cs: onRequestListener(Arguments[3])
```

Here is the site. The map is suppose to display on the contact us page [my site](http://derbyskillbuild.org.uk/contact-us/)

Comment: does not it work in any browser or only Chrome?

Comment: @yuyokk it doesn't work in any browser. Have posted a link for additional information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you have some code like this

```
<span <iframe="" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d1203.5916684263602!2d-1.460736!3d52.891122!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48798c70cf2a2d8f%3A0x193e5babe5839de!2sDerby+Skillbuild!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1426363000948" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0">
...
</span>
```

should be just

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d1203.5916684263602!2d-1.460736!3d52.891122!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48798c70cf2a2d8f%3A0x193e5babe5839de!2sDerby+Skillbuild!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1426363000948" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

[image]